# Navigation jetpack compose doesn't work directly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a problem with Navigation jetpack compose, the problem is navigation doesn't work directly and shows an empty screen, but if I scroll in the empty screen or do a long click after that navigation starts working and shows the screen that I put inside the navigation.

I search a lot about this problem and I don't find any solution.

I try to change the version  of the navigation compose and all the versions don't work.
and also when I use dark them work with out problme

except for version "2.4.0-alpha10" which works in some projects and doesn't in some projects

what is the problem? and why does this happen?

### build . gradle (Medule:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    def nav_version = "2.5.3"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
}
```

### build . gradle (project)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0-alpha02' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0-alpha02' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

### Main Actvity

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "younes") {
                        composable("younes") {
                            Text(text = "younes")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go to the Theme.file and change this line.

WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme

to

WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true

just change darkTheme to true